# Accessing Binary Search Tree in a Function

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Consider the following code:

```
#include "ClassB.h"

ClassA 
{
private:
  Vector<std::string> idVec;

public:
  int getTotal(ClassB& (*func) (std::string));
}

int ClassA::getTotal(ClassB& (*func) (std::string))
{
   int total = 0;
   for (int i:0; i < idVec.Size(); i++)
   {
      total += (*func) (idVec[i]).GetInt();
   }
 return total;
 }
```

---

```
ClassB
{
private:
  string id;
  int i;

public:  
   std::string getId();
   int getInt();
}
```

---

```
ClassB& accessTree(stD::string id);

main()
{
   BSTree<ClassB>  //Binary Search Tree
   ClassA a;
   //Assume id's get set.
   a.getTotal(accessTree);
}

ClassB& accessTree(stD::string id)
{
   //This is part I'm not 100% on.
}
```

The operators of ClassB have been overloaded. Consider id it's primary key if you will.

**Edit
So Thanks to Joachim Pileborg I've started to use/ learn about placeholders and binding.

Now what I'm about to post is my actual implementation but the concepts are the same. Unit = ClassB. R(aka Registration) = ClassA.

Calling Function

```
template<typename Ft>
unsigned Registration::GetCredits(Ft func)
{
  unsigned sum = 0;
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < GetSize(); i++)
     sum += results[i].GetCredits(func(results[i].GetUnit()));

  return sum;
}

Unit& accessTree(std::string id, BSTree<Unit>& tree)
{
  Unit tempU;
  tempU.SetId(id);
  return tree.search(tempU);
}
```

In main

```
R.GetCredits(std::bind(accessTree, _1, std::ref(uTree)));
```

undefined reference to `unsigned int Registration::GetCredits(std::_Placeholder<1>, std::reference_wrapper >))(std::string, BSTree&)> >(std::_Bind(std::_Placeholder<1>, std::reference_wrapper >))(std::string, BSTree&)>)'|

A little stuck at this point, what have I missed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions to your problems. The most obvious is of course to modify both the `getTotal` function and the callback function to accept the tree as an extra argument.

---

Another solution might be to not really use function pointers at all, but to make `getTotal` a template function, and pass the function type as the template argument. Then you could use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to pass a two-argument function to the `getTotal` without `getTotal` not really knowing about the actual function type.

Something like

```
template<typename Ft>
int ClassA::getTotal(Ft func)
{
    ...
    func(idVec[i]);
    ...
}
```

Use it like

```
ClassB& accessTree(const std::string& id, BSTree<ClassB>& tree);

...

using namespace std::placeholders;  // For `_1` etc.

BSTree<ClassB> tree;
a.getTotal(std::bind(accessTree, _1, std::ref(tree)));
```

([Reference for `std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref))

Comment: Hey Thanks Joachim,

I've had a read about placeholders and std::bind and not 100% sure what it does? 

Are you able to give a very rookie explanation? or another example?